# Redirect link in Opera Mobile to Android Browser

Tags: android

I have a web app that requires a WebKit-enabled browser. However, ~20 % of mobile browsers are Opera Mini/Mobile. Is there a way to suggest the handset to open a web site in the Stock Browser?

I'm thinking something along these lines:

```
<a href="#" onClick = "Android.Browser.open('mySite.xhtml')">Hello</a>
```

or

```
<html>
    <head>
        <suggested-browser="stockbrowser" />
    </head>
</html>
```

I could of course make an app out of it, but it is only a registration form..

Comment: Developer questions are considered off topic here, please see the FAQ: http://android.stackexchange.com/faq

Comment: It's 2012! Use graceful degradation, don't limit your users! Is it absolutely broken? You should just add a scrolling div, that displays in unsupported browser. **If you open a different browser without explicit permission, your users will be angry!**

Comment: I guess you're right; I'll attack this from a different angle. Thank you.